# Who had more power in the Weimar Government? The President or the Chancellor?

Tags: constitution, president, history, germany, power

This is referring to the Weimar government before Hitler rose to power- how much power did the original constitution give to each?

Comment: The President could appoint the chancellor so he had more powers, obviously

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Germany_%281919%E2%80%9345%29

Comment: It is hard to imagine a better illustration of a case where formal legal power and actual *de facto* power grew more misaligned.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the President of the Weimar Republic had powers like the President has in many countries, and more power added into his commitment within emergency state (Article 48 of the Weimar Republic Constitution).

The Reich Chancellor was one of the highest in the Government, which could replace the Reich President (Article 51).

Source/Research:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimar_Constitution
- http://www.zum.de/psm/weimar/weimar_vve.php#Third%20Chapter

**Edit:** There was also a Reichstag arson (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_fire and its references). No matter the arsonist was a Communist or just a fool (and so "flagged" as Communist), it helped to justify the request for an emergency decree and, possibly, mass arrests of communists (including Reichstag members). It may enabled Hitler's party to form a Reichstag majority.

Comment: The recall of the president was much more complicated then you make it: It needed a two-thirds majority in the Reichstag _and_ a referendum. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Germany_%281919%E2%80%9345%29).

Comment: It wasn't sufficient for the majority, but it served the Nazis as a fig leaf for introducing the dictatorship. They used it to pass emergency legislation that hindered political parties directly ahead of an election, banned the communist party, gave their paramilitary brown shirts basically police level privileges and after the election took the seats of the communists as they had been on the ballot despite already being in concentration camps or on the run. They still came out short of a majority and a super majority needed for the constitutional amendment which is why they coerced the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In the Weimar Republic, the president was elected directly by the people every seven years. He was commander-in-chief of the Reichswehr and had extensive rights to emergency legislation, and he could also dissolve parliament. Even contemporaries saw the president as a “replacement emperor”. So defenetly the president had more power, in opinion of many people even to much power. It was president Hindenburg who appointed Hitler.

I am listing the important aticles from the [Weimar constitution](https://www.verfassungen.de/de19-33/verf19-i.htm) refering to president:

> Article 43. The office of Reich President lasts seven years.
> Re-election is permitted
>
> Before the deadline expires, the Reich President can be removed by
> popular vote at the request of the Reichstag. The decision of the
> Reichstag requires a two-thirds majority. The decision prevents the
> Reich President from continuing to exercise his office. The rejection
> of the dismissal by referendum is considered a new election and
> results in the dissolution of the Reichstag.
>
> The Reich President cannot be prosecuted without the consent of the
> Reichstag.
>
> see the law on the pension of the Reich President of December 31, 1922
> (RGBl. 1923 I p. 53).
>
> Article 45. The Reich President represents the Reich under
> international law. He concludes alliances and other treaties with
> foreign powers on behalf of the empire. He authenticates and receives
> the messengers.
>
> The declaration of war and the conclusion of peace are made by Reich
> law.
>
> Alliances and treaties with foreign states that relate to subjects of
> Reich legislation require the approval of the Reichstag.
>
> Article 46. The Reich President appoints and dismisses Reich officials
> and officers, unless otherwise provided by law. He can have the right
> of appointment and dismissal exercised by other authorities.
>
> see the ordinance on the appointment and dismissal of Reich officials
> of June 14, 1922 (RGBl. I p. 577).
>
> Article 47. The Reich President has supreme command over the entire
> armed forces of the Reich.
>
> see the decree regarding the transfer of supreme command of the
> Wehrmacht to the Reich Defense Minister of August 20, 1919 (RGBl. p.
> 1475) and the Defense Act of March 23, 1921 (RGBl. I p. 329).
>
> Article 48. If a Land fails to fulfill the duties incumbent on it
> under the Imperial Constitution or the Imperial Laws, the Reich
> President may, by means of the armed forces, compel it to do so.
>
> If public safety and order are seriously disturbed or endangered in
> the German Reich, the President of the Reich can take the necessary
> measures to restore public safety and order, if necessary with the
> help of armed forces. To this end, it may temporarily suspend, in
> whole or in part, the fundamental rights set out in Articles 114, 115,
> 117, 118, 123, 124 and 153
>
> The Reich President shall immediately inform the Reichstag of all
> measures taken pursuant to Paragraph 1 or Paragraph 1 of this article.
> The measures are to be suspended at the request of the Reichstag.
>
> In the event of imminent danger, the state government can take interim
> measures of the type described in paragraph 2 for its area. The
> measures are to be suspended at the request of the Reich President or
> the Reichstag.
>
> A Reich law determines the details.
>
> such a Reich law has not been passed.
>
> Article 49. The Reich President exercises the right of pardon for the
> Reich. Imperial amnesties require an Imperial law.

Articles 46-49 are showing the power the president had. As mentioned in some other answer the parliament had the posibility to get rid of the president (article 43), but it was harder to achieve then even impeachment in USA and had eventualy cosequences for the parliament itself.

Comment: That the president (or another head of the state - like King/Queen) appoints the prime minister is rather commonplace in parliamentary democracies - this is one of *few* powers that the heads of the state have in such systems.

Comment: @Roger Vadim Yes this is true, but the presidents and kings you are talking about have to folow the decision of parliament and appoint the person the parlaments wants. They can not decide themself whom to appoint.

Comment: they usually appoint the person who is likely to be able to form the government coalition. This is not necessarily the head of the biggest party. In some cases they can appoint a person from a small party or even not a parliament member - usually in cases of constitutional crisis. Mario Monti is the most recent example that comes to mind

Comment: @Roger Vadim OK, but even in this  situation the candidat needs to be aproved by the parliament.

Comment: yes, that's correct - the head of state only nominates the candidate, who has the best chances to be approved.

Comment: @RogerVadim Usually that is a more or less ceremonial act where the parliament tells the president who they would like as chancellor and the president then "proposes" that person and the parliament approves the pick. Hindenburg however regularly appointed a chancellor, that person received a vote of no confidence and stayed in office until re-elections. Though as they had no parliamentary majority to pass laws, the legislative power was rather exercised by the president passing emergency decrees. So the otherwise ceremonial act was actually exercised to near dictatorial power extend.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR the president.

The actual story is more complicated. A lot of the Weimar constitution is a remainder or result of the system that came before it, which was a constitutional monarchy of a federal state.

So the emperor was the head of state of the whole federation and also the king of the biggest state of that federation who had both legislative and executive options and was leader of the armed forces, but was constraint by a constitution.

The king then appoints a government lead by a chancellor who also serves as prime minister of the biggest state and who is chairman of the Bundesrat,the representation of the governments of the member states. Which by the constitution was supposed to be the most important organ, yet in practice voted mostly in line with the biggest state and was thus rather seen as an extension of the government and of little significance of it's own.

While on the other hand there was a parliament which, was the only elected institution and had some control over the chancellor yet could not elect or remove him and which could initiate or block legislature but which had as the most important duty the obligation to pass the budget which provided some power. The head of state could also dispel it and was it didn't form on it's own but must be summoned by the emperor but that was rather ceremonial and if dispelled a new one would need to be elected within a short time frame.

So the centers of power were not necessarily with democratic institutions and not necessarily where they were supposed to be given the constitution. Like the military, the entourage of the monarchy, the bureaucrats and whatnot had way more power than intended.

So when Germany lost WWI things were about to change. The socialists wanted a revolution and rebelled replacing the Reichstag with a Nationalconvention, while the social democrats, weary of what had happened in Russia about a year prior, rather wanted a controlled reform than a chaotic revolution. While the military and aristocratic elites also suddenly liked the idea of parliamentarism because it meant they could blame someone else for their failure in WWI. From 1916 onwards Germany had been a military dictatorship the people responsible for losing WWI floated the narrative that they would have won if the parliament hadn't backstabbed them with their surrendered, when in reality their refusal to negotiate peace when there was still something left to negotiate placed parliament in the position where they had to accept the Treaty of Versailles or fight on and cease to exist as a country and they knew that.

Now while the social democrats would have been fine with a reformed constitutional monarchy the socialists had already made plans to proclaim a socialist republic so within 2 hours first the social democrats and later the socialists proclaimed the republic while only the former lasted, with the support of the old elites.

As a consequence some reforms were made. The head of state was now electable, the center of power was supposed to be the parliament, the government was elect- and removable by the parliament which also had the legislative power, while the president kept lots of the powers vested in the former president (emperor) and depending who you ask was either a replacement emperor, a leader with a popular mandate or a symbol of unification of the country or a deterrent for any other demagogue trying to take a similar position.

convert gave a nice overview of the powers of the president https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79931/42766

Though given these alone it's not quite apparent why the president is the more powerful figure.

Because de jure the chancellor is, as head of government and likely leader of the largest government faction as well as part of the coalition majority, supposed to be the more relevant figure. Like how it is in the modern German system where the president is #1 in protocol but where world leaders would usually consult with the chancellor, as that's the person in charge of the government.

However as one might have heard, Weimar Germany was a democracy without democrats. Meaning that it was a pretty progressive democratic system which was ahead of many others, but few people actually liked it. The military was taking on a deep state existence, aided by the fact that no one was willing to snitch to the allies that they undermined the 100,000 men restriction for the army, pretty much the entire time. The conservatives blamed the lost war on the social democrats and their revolution, which they did everything to curb. The socialists and communists hated it because the social democrats had done everything to curb the revolution and were still hoping the revolution would come and the "center" (not to be confused with the party of the same name) that kinda liked, it was hence VERY VERY diverse in opinions and didn't get along very well.

So despite parliament having a 4 year tenure (and so would the government elected by it), there's no government that lasted even 2 years, most of them didn't even come close to that line. 21 governments in 14 years is really a lot. So from the start the role of the president was interpreted as much more powerful than it was intended to be. Because a lot of the "stuff that never happens" scenarios that are part of many job descriptions of heads of state, but seldom become and issue, actually were used as such.

So for example that infamous article 48 was not just interpreted as applying existing laws but it was also seen as an option for the president to PASS emergency decrees that have the character of laws. As convert has mentioned the specifics were supposed to be dealt with by a federal law, but that never happened so a lot of that came down to political praxis and decisions by judges. And the social democratic president had to already set a lot of precedents of that kind to deal with the various uprisings by the communists and the rights wing actors. So that when Paul von Hindenburg was elected (an outspoken anti-democrat) a proposed law to curb that power was simply rejected and not admitted for debate.

Though while chaotic from the beginning things really came to a head when in 1930 the "grand coalition" failed, that is the coalition of all or at least the biggest democratic parties (despite their MASSIVE ideological differences). So at this point there was no parliamentary majority and parliament was largely disfunctional. At which point Hindenburg proceeded with something called "presidential cabinets". So technically the ability of the president to propose a government was meant to be rather ceremonial, parliament would appoint a chancellor, the president would propose them and the parliament would approve that person.

Now parliament wasn't able to propose a chancellor that had a majority backing, so instead Hindenburg himself appointed people he liked and parliament could either give them a vote of no confidence upon which that process starts anew or accept them. At first they were accepted as minority governments that were tolerated by the parties in favor of the republic but usually sooner or later they proposed legislation that wasn't popular and so a majority thus were disposed of.

Upon which the president dispelled parliament (causing new elections), while in the mean time the government stayed in office but without any legislative power, so that's where the president came in who just made their proposals laws without the approval of parliament simply by means of emergency decrees. The further that goes the more daring he became and one of the last cabinets consisted purely of aristocrats that were elected by no one and had no popular mandate at all. Though apparently some of his advisors told him that this government was so unpopular that they would have to fight the socialist, social democrats, center and Nazis all at once and so they stepped down and tried an uneasy alliances with the Nazis. With these attempts resulting in a normalization of the Nazis (SA ban lifted and so on), while the conservatives lost ground. So that in the end, rather than a conservative revolution with the Nazis as minions, it resulted in a Nazi revolution with conservatives as backbone.

So while not intended the president ended up being the far more powerful position.

Also just for completion Hitler was the last of those presidentially appointed chancellors, who received basically an instant vote of no confidence but used a fire in the parliament as a fig leaf to ban the communist party and hinder political activism ahead of the scheduled elections for the new chancellor. With all the instigation and intimidation he still only scored a plurality of 42% and further used shenanigans and intimidation to coerce the remaining parliament to pass a constitutional amendment to essentially make him dictator to cope with the immanent emergency which gave him the executive and legislative privilege to not give a shit about parliament altogether and from there on it became the worlds largest choir because apart from singing there wasn't much going on there anymore. The president kept silent upon his death upon which Hitler merged the two offices to "Führer".

Also the Nazis themselves celebrated the date of the Hitler's appointment as chancellor as the "power grab", despite being near instantly removed. Which kinda hints at the significance of the fire in parliament and the enabling act as more of performative fig leafs rather than actually political relevant stunts.

Like the existing checks and balances only matter if people care about them and if the president isn't willing to rectify a situation that he created and if brown shirts receive police privileges the official legality becomes secondary as the political battleground is no longer in democratic institutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Weimar republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimar_Republic) was *a parliamentary republic*, largely similar to the modern parliamentary republics. The president had some limited powers, which are typical in such cases, notably the power to appoint the chancellor (just like the president of the Federal Republic of Germany does today or as the King/Queen does in Britain.) The chancellor had the full executive authority - at least in the peace time.

**National-Socialists' non-democratic rise to power**
It is worth pointing out a widespread myth that Nazis came to power peacefully, via a democratic process. In fact, Nazis never had the support of more than a third of the German population - neither in parliamentary elections, nor in the presidential elections, where Hitler had presented himself against Hindenburg. Even this share of vote was achieved by means of voter intimidation, threats to candidates from other parties and sometimes even physical aggression - indeed, by the time of coming to power Nazis commanded about 2 millions of Stormtroopers (=Brown shirts), who were largely hardened veterans of WW1 (like Hitler himself). One could compare this number to the official size of the German army permitted by the Versailles peace agreement - 100 thousand people. That Hitler was appointed the chancellor and that his party was the biggest party in the Reichstag didn't make him a dictator - he needed a super-majority in order to vote him with the emergency powers, where he would have both executive and legislative authority. This was achieved by getting communists expelled from the Reichstag following the Reichstag fire provocation, making alliance with some other parties, and [intimidating the rest of deputies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_rise_to_power#Chancellor_to_dictator):

> Employing his characteristic mix of negotiation and intimidation, Hitler offered the possibility of friendly co-operation, promising not to threaten the Reichstag, the President, the States or the Churches if granted the emergency powers. **With Nazi paramilitary encircling the building, he said: "It is for you, gentlemen of the Reichstag to decide between war and peace". The Centre Party, having obtained promises of non-interference in religion, joined with conservatives in voting for the Act (only the Social Democrats voted against).**

After Hinderburg's death Hitler also assumed the office of the president, only then accumulating in his hands the complete dictatorial power.

Ironically, the Storm-troopers, led by [Gregor Strasser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Strasser) and [Ernst Röhm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_R%C3%B6hm), represented the more *socialist wing of the Nazi party*: in particular, for them revolution was not over with Nazi rise to power - they expected the dismantling of the big fortunes in favor of simple people. Hitler, who after coming to power preferred to make an alliance with big industrialists and aristocracy, got rid of the Brown shorts in the event known as the [Night of the Long Knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives).

Comment: The Bundespräsident does not actually appoint the chancellor of the FRG, instead he nominates someone who then has to be elected by a majority of members of the Bundestag. If that majority does not come to pass, the Bundestag can freely elect anyone else. Outside of the Westminster system there are very few (if any) parliamentary democracies where the head of government is appointed at will by the head of state.

Comment: @xyldke this is correct - technically the head of state usually only nominates the head ofthe government - they still need to master the majority if votes in parliament.

Answer (score -2):

The President could appoint the chancellor so he had more powers.

Also at the time of Weimar republic there was rule by decree (effectively, dictatorship of the president): the president was invested with extraordinary powers because the parties could not agree on a coalition.

Comment: That's not obvious at all. In many countries the president (or even a monarch) formally appoints a prime minister that is effectively chosen by the parliament. Even if the president had a bigger role than that, the ability to call up new elections or to fire a head of government make a big difference beyond merely appointing one. I don't know about Weimar but this answer fails to support its own claims adequately.

Comment: @Relaxed Hindenburg appointed Hitler.

Comment: So? I know that but that's completely unrelated to my point. If anything, if you just look at this one event naïvely, it supports the notion that Hindenburg did not have that much power, because Hitler is the one that became an all-powerful dictator.

Comment: @Relaxed this is because Hindenburg did not oppose and died.

Comment: Yes, that's the “naïve” part about it, but still. You seem to assume that nominating someone necessarily implies great powers, beyond that of the nominee, but it does not. Reminding us that Hindenburg appointed Hitler, as fateful as that particular appointment might have been, simply reiterates the same assumption, without addressing my criticism.

Comment: @Relaxed Hindenburg had all constitutional powers to remove Hitler and appoint somebody else. He just did not want to.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know the Weimar Republic, it's entirely possible the president was very powerful and you're welcome to make your case (no need for comments, simply edit your answer). But the fact that he could appoint (or even remove) the Chancellor simply does not imply he had more powers, much less “obviously”. It's a simple point really, no need to discuss it endlessly.

Comment: @Relaxed it does. It is obvious.

Comment: Well, no, cf. many contemporary parliamentary democracies from Germany or Italy to the UK and the Netherlands.

Comment: @Relaxed In modern Germany the President, I think, cannot appoint the chancellor at will, without taking into account the legislature. In the UK the queen indeed has mere power than anybody else.

Comment: The notion that the Queen has more power than anybody else is absurd. And indeed, in modern democracies, the head of government has to be approved by a majority of the parliament. That's precisely my point: Things like this matter, you can't write “He appoints the chancellor, therefore he has more powers”, that's not how it works.

Comment: Incidentally, you have already mentioned two relevant factors in comments (the ability to remove the chancellor at will, the role of parliament), why not add all that to your answer instead of arguing pointlessly they support your original reasoning?

Comment: @Relaxed "The notion that the Queen has more power than anybody else is absurd." - it is not absurd, it is just the fact. That the Queen does not rule it just a state propaganda (she does). I already mentioned that in Weimar Republic at the time the president was invested with extraordinary powers (rule by decree). This happened years before Hitler and in fact was equal to dictatorship. The President by these powers could appoint chancellor without consulting Reichstag (while normally without extraordinary powers he should).

Comment: The fact is that she does not. If your intellectual framework leads you to believe that she does effectively rule the Commonwealth realms, then that's what needs revising. But if you really believe that, I am not surprised that you are unable to present relevant arguments in your answer.

Comment: "The fact is that she does not." - wrong. She rules by secret letters, by expressing her opinions. There is no need to use her constitutional powers every time, just because everybody knows her powers, and they are huge. There is no need to remove your subordinate every time you want him to do something. Also the Queen can appoint the PM without the consent of the Parliament, she just does not need to do it usually.